# Automatically Configuring client workstation in a Lan

Tags: configuration, automation

Suppose we have a Lan with X clients workstations and Y servers, the servers are running different network services (web, e-mail, directory service...) both client and servers might run either Linux or Windows.

To consume these services users of the client workstations will need to install and configure client software (web client, mail client) on their machines.

Now If we have X=100 and the users are totally average users, is there any mean to automatically deploy configured client software in the client workstations?

Many configuration tools exists such as Puppet or Chef but they seem to be server oriented.
Protocols Like DHCP serves only IP Addresses.

Is there any tool or network service that allow clients to autoconfigure themselves?

Comment: "we have a Lan with X clients workstations" - What kind of clients? Windows? Linux? Other?

Comment: What OS on clients?

Comment: Without more specific details, you're only going to get quite non-specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Grant's answer, an ideal solution (in an all windows environment) would typically involve using three approaches to managing software and settings on client workstations.

- You would use group policy (via active directory) to manage settings,
  permissions, configurations, and restrictions.
- You would use WDS (Windows Deployment Services) to manage imaging of
  client workstations. WDS can be used to maintain a standard operating
  environment so that you can easily and rapidly deploy windows to a
  client computer with all the desired settings and applications
  pre-installed, and pre-configured.
- You would use SCCM (System Center Configuration Manager) to provide ongoing maintenance for application deployment and device management. SCCM is a powerful tool, but is often overkill in smaller environments, where it's just easier to maintain a solid SOE using WDS.

Comment: +1 that's what I wanted to type but couldn't from my phone.

Comment: Thanks! How about Linux environments?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are.

In the windows world you have active directory with group policy.  And imaging through windows deployment services or microsoft configuration manager or other tools.